# How to transform PSClass into module?

Tags: oop, powershell

I consider [PSClass - Object Oriented Scripting in Powershell](http://psclass.codeplex.com/) as a very promising way to use simple OOP notations in my PowerShell productions.

The beauty of the original PSClass.ps1 construction is that it gives possibility to use very communicative/self-descriptive scriptblock in `New-PSClass` invocation.

It is constructed as a script that you have to run before any OOP syntax can be used in you own code.

My ambition is to convert it into standard PoweShell module (ie. PSClass.psm1) that could be imported by `Import-Module` cmdlet.
Unfortunately, when content of the PSClass.ps1 is directly embedded into PSClass.psm1 subroutines `note`, `constructor`, `property`, `method` are not visible for `Export-ModuleMember`. 
Even if I use simple PSClass.psm1 definition like:

```
. .\PSClass.ps1

Export-ModuleMember -Function @('New-PSClass')
```

still subroutines `note`, `constructor`, `property`, `method` cannot be exported by `Export-ModuleMember`.

Has anybody any hint, how to make PSClass.ps1 script fully functional module with preserved self-descriptive scriptblock in `New-PSClass` invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would rename PSClass.ps1 to PSClass.psm1 and the put the `Export-ModuleMember` command inside the PSClass.psm1 file.  I don't see any value in dot sourcing PSClass.ps1 inside PSClass.psm1.  Now you have two classes to pass redist rather than just one.

After looking at this script, I would add this to the end of the PSClass.psm1 file:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function New-PSClass, constructor, note, property, method
```

Comment: I had done it as a first trial. It had failed. Have you succeeded?

Comment: Ah I see the problem.  The constructor, note et al functions are nested within the New-PSClass function.  AFAICT you can't export nested functions. Those functions would have to be brought up to module scope and who knows what that will break.